# Aquireing the entire string sent to the shell for execution

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that looks like this (called job_result.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash
$* && zenity --title "Job result" --info --text "SUCSESS: Job '$*'completed" && while pidof zenity > /dev/null; do /usr/bin/wmctrl -a "Job Result" && sleep 2; done
```

When i execute it with:

```
$ ./job_result.sh echo "arf" && sleep 10
```

I want the following to happen:

```
$ echo "arf" && sleep 10 && zenity --title "Job result" --info --text "SUCSESS: Job '$*'completed" && while pidof zenity > /dev/null; do /usr/bin/wmctrl -a "Job Result" && sleep 2; done
```

But it seems the following is happening:

```
$ echo "arf" && zenity --title "Job result" --info --text "SUCSESS: Job '$*'completed" && while pidof zenity > /dev/null; do /usr/bin/wmctrl -a "Job Result" && sleep 2; done
```

Question: How do i get hold of the entire shell argument? And not just the part until &&?

Answer (score 1):

try putting quotes

```
$ ./job_result.sh "echo 'arf' && sleep 10"
```

here's a guess of what you want, and can do

put your parameters in a variable in another file. then when you want to use it, source the file eg

```
$ cat my_shell_libraries
export var="echo 'arf' && sleep 10"
$ . my_shell_libraries
$ ./job_result.sh $var
```

Comment: Is there a way to wrap this in a function so that i can write:
$ ./job_result.sh echo "arf" && sleep 10

Or catch all the parameters without '' encapsultaion?

Comment: do you run this script manually everytime? or is it going to be scheduled as cron job?

Comment: Manually.

I intend to use it as a wrapper for jobs that takes longer than 1 minute. Like mm -b in $ANDROID_ROOT.

Comment: Any ideas? I can't figure it out... iv'e tried googleing alot since (and before) my original post...